# Can I use a register as a loop counter?

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm, calling-convention

Since the calling convention of a function states which registers are preserved, can a register be used as a loop counter?

I first thought that the `ecx` register is used as a loop counter, but after finding out that an `stdcall` function I have used has not preserved the value of `ecx`, I thought otherwise.

Is there a register that is guaranteed (by mostly used calling conventions at least) to be preserved?

**Note:** I don't have a problem in using a stack variable as a loop counter, I just want to make sure that it is the only way.

Comment: you could push `ecx` on the stack and restore it before you `ret`, or you could just use another register

Comment: `push ecx` before making the `stdcall` and `pop ecx` after the call returns, each time through the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any general-purpose register, and occasionally others, as the loop counter (just not the stack pointer of course ☺).

Either you use one to loop manually, i.e. replace…

```
loop label
```

… with…

```
dec ebp
jnz label
```

… which is faster anyway (because AMD (and later Intel, when they caught up, MHz-wise) artificially slowed down the `loop` instruction as otherwise, Windows® and some Turbo Pascal compiled software crashed).

Or you just save the counter in between:

```
label:
    push ecx
    call func
    pop ecx
    loop label
```

Both are standard strategies.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a register that is guaranteed (by mostly used calling conventions at least) to be preserved?

You can choose any free register in your own code if your loop code will not call any external entity.

If your loop code will call an external entity where the only guaranteed contract is the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and calling convention then you must save/restore your registers and make the register choice case-by-case.

Quoting Agner Fog's excellent paper [Calling conventions for different C++ compilers and operating systems](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf):

> **6 Register usage**
>
> The rules for register usage depend on the operating system, as shown in table 4. Scratch registers are registers that can be used for temporary storage without restrictions (also called caller-save or volatile registers). Callee-save registers are registers that you have to save before using them and restore after using them (also called non-volatile registers). You can rely on these registers having the same value after a call as before the call...
>
> [image]
>
> ...

See also:

- [Wikipedia: x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)